# Exlude a directory in .htaccess with RedirectMatch for Wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I change my Wordpress permalink structure from %year%/%months%/ to %postname%

So i create this mod alias rules in **.htaccess** but i have a problem:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /\d{4}/\d{2}/([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1
```

The rules also redirect the images under the wp-content directory, so **domainname.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/name.jpg** become **domainname.com/name.jpg**

I can't use RewriteCond because this RedirecMatch is mod_alias, i try to use `!^/(wp-content.*)$` but doesn't work.

**How can i solve**? It's better to use RedirectMach or RewriteRule (i haven't changed the server)?

Can you post a **better regex**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably stick with using mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias because it'll interfere with wordpress' mod_rewrite rules. Both mod_rewrite and mod_alias affect the same request URI at different points in the URL-file processing pipeline, so you could end up getting redirected and rewritten at the same time.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/([^/]+?)(/?)(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. I use: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/([^/]+?)(/?)(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Do i use this rules after # BEGIN WordPress and before mod_rewrite.c?

Comment: @DarioSalvelli You need to have your redirects *before* the wordpress rules. The wordpress rules do wholesale routing to `index.php` which isn't what you want when you redirect the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^` and `$`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\d{4}/\d{2}/([^/]+)(/?)(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1
```